# Enable WebGL w/ intel drivers in chrome

Tags: video, google-chrome, intel-graphics, webgl

My glxinfo: http://pastebin.com/drbaMaxN

My lspci: http://pastebin.com/RwsVfEdu

I've enabled "Override software rendering" in chrome://flags, but chrome://gpu still tells me 'WebGL: unavailable'. Is this just a problem with my video card?